# Connecting Python to MySQL: Obtaining S&P500 Symbols

Tags: python, mysql, server

so I'm trying to connect Python to MySQL. I'm trying to develop an algo- trading system.  At present, I'm trying to populate a table called *symbols* with company symbols listed on the S&P500.  MySQL has the correct password, however, MySQL doesn't seem to think so. It seems to think the password is 'yes'...?  Please see the code from my python script below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#insert_symbols.py

from __future__ import print_function 

import datetime
from math import ceil

import bs4
import MySQLdb as mdb
import requests

def obtain_parse_wiki_snp500():
"""
Download and parse the Wikipedia list of S&P500
constituents using requests and BeautifulSoup.

Returns a list of tuples for to add to MySQL
"""
# Stores the current time, for the created_at record
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

# Use requests and BeautifulSoup to download the 
# list of S&P500 companies and obtain the symbol table
response = requests.get(
     "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

# This selects the first table, using CSS Selector syntax
# and then ignores the header row ([1:])
symbolslist = soup.select('table')[0].select('tr')[1:]

# Obtain the symbol information for each 
# row in the S&P500 constituent table
symbols = []
for i, symbol in enumerate(symbolslist):
    tds = symbol.select('td')
    symbols.append(
        (
           tds[0].select('a')[0].text, # Ticker
           'stock',
           tds[1].select('a')[0].text, # Name
           tds[3].text, # Sector
           'USD', now, now
        )
     )
return symbols

def insert_snp500_symbols(symbols):
"""
Insert the S&P500 symbols into the MySQL database
"""

# Connect to the MySQL instance 
db_host = 'localhost'
db_user = 'sec_user'
db_pass = '*********'
db_name = 'securities_master'
con = mdb.connect(
      host=db_host, user=db_user, passwd=db_pass, db=db_name
)

# Create the insert strings
column_str = """ticker, instrument, name, sector,
             currency, created_date, last_updated_date
             """
insert_str = ("%s, " * 7)[:-2]
final_str = "INSERT INTO symbol (%s) VALUES (%s)" % \
    (column_str, insert_str)

# Using the MySQL connection, carry out
# an INSERT INTO for every symbol
with con:
   cur = con.cursor()
   cur.executemany(final_str, symbols)

if __name__ == "__main__":
symbols = obtain_parse_wiki_snp500()
insert_snp500_symbols(symbols)
print("%s symbols were successfully added." % len(symbols))

When I run this script, I get the following output:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./symbols_mysql.py", line 82, in <module>
insert_snp500_symbols(symbols)
File "./symbols_mysql.py", line 63, in insert_snp500_symbols
host=db_host, user=db_user, passwd=db_pass, db=db_name
File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb    /init__.py",    line 81, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb  /connections.py", line 204, in __init__
```

gs, **kwargs2)
_   mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user '  sec_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

I'm really sorry about how messy this is.  I've had a look around to try and find some sort of answer but the no avail.  I'm OK with Python, however, MySQL is still a bit of a new beast to me! Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!

Thanks

Comment: "using password: YES" is MySQL telling you that access was attempted _with_ a password, not that the password was "YES".

Comment: NB/ 2 lines of the code aren't inside the code block, just below it.

Comment: I suspect you have added `db_user` as a MySQL user, but you haven't [granted that user permission](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql) to `db_name`.

Comment: @kfb.  Solved this by adding a different user and then granted that user the privileges etc. Thanks for the advice, my script now works perfectly!